# Input DCDC buck filter design equation

Tags: dc-dc-converter, design, buck, capacitance, input

I am asking because I am confused.  I cannot resolve this issue since yesterday and I am still learning.

I was reading  article about Input DC-DC buck filter. Each of the two articles say something different.

https://www.eetimes.com/choosing-the-right-input-caps-for-your-buck-converter/

The first confusion is about VESR.

https://www.eetimes.com/wp-content/uploads/media-1054716-gif3.gif

During 0 and \$\Delta t\$ the input capacitor current is negative, how is it that the VESR curve is positive? Is it a mistake from the article?

The second thing really really confusing. I do not understand why we do not have the same current in the ESR resistance ESL inductance with capacitance.

https://www.eetimes.com/wp-content/uploads/media-1054717-gif4.gif

As you can see equation [1](https://www.eetimes.com/wp-content/uploads/media-1054717-gif4.gif) in the ESR and ESL we have the current

\$I_O-0.5  I_{RIPPLE}\$

and in the capacitance

\$I_O-I_{IN}\$

But why? Is there something I do not understand with series component, I mean it should be the same current in the 3 components?

In my point of view, between 0 and \$\Delta t\$ the current

\$i_C(t)= I_{input}- I_L\\
=I_O D -(I_O - \Delta IL/2 + \Delta ILt/(Dt))\\ 
= I_O D -  I_O + \Delta IL/2 - \Delta ILt/(Dt)\\ 
= (I_O (D-1)+\Delta IL(1/2-t/D*T)\$

Am I right?

If we do the average of that we do not at all what we have in equation [1](https://www.eetimes.com/wp-content/uploads/media-1054717-gif4.gif).

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please review the edit to see if your question is the same as intended.

Comment: @skvery No space before question mark.